# Given xml files, how to implement SAML protocol in a Java webapp

Tags: java, jsp, saml, spring-saml, onelogin

Recently I have been asked to implement the SAML protocol in an existing project

My experience with this protocol is 0, so after hours and hours of research I ask this question here to see if anyone can help me.

Identity provider IdP (first image) and Service Provider SP (second image):
[image]
[image]

**[What I've tried so far]**
I decided to try [OneLogin's SAML Java Toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml), I am trying to run the sample project

And here is the **onelogin.saml.properties**, I have filled in the properties file based on the xml info from the pictures:

```
#  If 'strict' is True, then the Java Toolkit will reject unsigned
#  or unencrypted messages if it expects them signed or encrypted
#  Also will reject the messages if not strictly follow the SAML
onelogin.saml2.strict =  false

# Enable debug mode (to print errors)
onelogin.saml2.debug =  true


#  Service Provider Data that we are deploying
#

#  Identifier of the SP entity  (must be a URI)
#onelogin.saml2.sp.entityid = http://localhost:8080/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/metadata.jsp
onelogin.saml2.sp.entityid = https://APP.seat.vwg

# Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
#  returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
# URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned
#onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = http://localhost:8080/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/acs.jsp
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = https://app.seat.vwg

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-POST binding only
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST

# Specifies info about where and how the <Logout Response> message MUST be
# returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
#onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.url = http://localhost:8080/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/sls.jsp
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.url = https://app.seat.vwg

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <LogoutResponse> or sending the <LogoutRequest>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to
# represent the requested subject.
# Take a look on lib/Saml2/Constants.php to see the NameIdFormat supported
onelogin.saml2.sp.nameidformat = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified

# Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
# the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters

onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = MIIHfTCCBWWgAwIBAgIUZjZNYuKAdK9UTGVUrZUWCiGoUlQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQk0xGTAXBgNVBAoTEFF1b1ZhZGlzIExpbWl0ZWQxIzAhBgNVBAMTGlF1b1ZhZGlzIEdsb2JhbCBTU0wgSUNBIEczMB4XDTE4MDkxMjEwMDY1MVoXDTIwMDkxMjEwMTYwMFowfTELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxFjAUBgNVBAgMDU5pZWRlcnNhY2hzZW4xEjAQBgNVBAcMCVdvbGZzYnVyZzEWMBQGA1UECgwNVm9sa3N3YWdlbiBBRzEMMAoGA1UECwwDRlNBMRwwGgYDVQQDDBNhbS5zZWF0LnZ3Z3JvdXAuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn75gwMRZb95CF9CattUUjy1PiRWug/qw8JgIXIRwkRnBhkXYRCACqurqejOmBFrRvCAAqmgFlHeitQT3rt4ZZe7CvRzKDK4f1/Gga7STcGArgcMNgk+uliUN62ciS3iAGhGwOKOiIu2dy3jKDJV9i3GFRmTH5eymNonaIFJct6d1t/7DHQv7HICtnJ79SS8+q6dOg0Hg/tQanXQqGbkRQARQz3V25OshDWzBlpHE3aRHK/R07VDYK94hv4WrAHVtzPbKCQ08OPzyJ0ZILYYug4Yh+iMgTGeMxyyF2IfSkiTFihXOw1JS7Kcu6TnfxZLWuEg3Q3mT48olMegiGtre3wIDAQABo4IDIzCCAx8wCQYDVR0TBAIwADAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSzEom1qUs1vBUA8IDp2HiH8RN8djBzBggrBgEFBQcBAQRnMGUwNwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGK2h0dHA6Ly90cnVzdC5xdW92YWRpc2dsb2JhbC5jb20vcXZzc2xnMy5jcnQwKgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGHmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnF1b3ZhZGlzZ2xvYmFsLmNvbTAeBgNVHREEFzAVghNhbS5zZWF0LnZ3Z3JvdXAuY29tMFEGA1UdIARKMEgwRgYMKwYBBAG+WAACZAEBMDYwNAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWKGh0dHA6Ly93d3cucXVvdmFkaXNnbG9iYWwuY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMBMDoGA1UdHwQzMDEwL6AtoCuGKWh0dHA6Ly9jcmwucXVvdmFkaXNnbG9iYWwuY29tL3F2c3NsZzMuY3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSKJzxfUrEK9KUNhpSzyZywsyzr6zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwggF9BgorBgEEAdZ5AgQCBIIBbQSCAWkBZwB3AFYUBpov18Ls0/XhvUSyPsdGdrm8mRFcwO+UmFXWidDdAAABZc1H/woAAAQDAEgwRgIhAJTgY89lKcM/IbeHPLQGcKPu+Y3jhpQD6TXR65lwaeb3AiEA2cOlc3QNjqNibcnWmi/Dp1DFb7mF+gdNfWofJK8QB+kAdQDuS723dc5guuFCaR+r4Z5mow9+X7By2IMAxHuJeqj9ywAAAWXNR/7KAAAEAwBGMEQCIHL9/RrGtAbQTi6junapzHZXhV/Z9dCmJJf/QOTmMgtDAiA8U6fPZnCmkiDmmO73i+GuOAEee6pFak0K7l/PXyBbtQB1AFWB1MIWkDYBSuoLm1c8U/DA5Dh4cCUIFy+jqh0HE9MMAAABZc1H/tAAAAQDAEYwRAIgE9l3X93KXJ1UYaQZzqhhV6CTw4cF4cMGmwIn4RAEHVACIG2JtJKF4oVb4mWgltMS+reECZy8HKkMG3HOGjzDMjusMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4ICAQCImbF0UdTRn7PLoL7ETylybmXUKuVgCjwB8dL+Jn29ibo8Bn3rXo3zhJict6HDWTSz2wqBWbh99yliD/ejwG0LZ88fjLUona2ept9STtKSKJcsRpQf0Ie749wLOxtiGQ6KyKdNIz8ggK/xAz92h7HuJKrfAqkHxXW2HsSDAO0OXpedD7vvzRDFuOQVq0kSLFpYTLklY15KPeDzjhWSYkxR4tQ9MMjX2yvVgzR5BghXUmdVuDZuqlO44Y9FwsIH3PmX7d/4mdpAEIks/mZswulaoD4FsN6TNXtEvrFwGBfxW7ACcYgYwKzzCRcXqwDIfmeX8oslPf5NgMP0n4QTzVy8hJtO1ojBHeFfB/qpISDIli9TczSOcHgjkDq5GVzTFjLNSremBxaQ6hlI/h6gLQzZlqucYFtzja07VFsDeAZ5nGY6fR1gof6D7i08IE9JKUKsDI6sgqZLBhtDqhQaXfXy0s0hqvxd4pBGC17/13FxClCCoMGLA1ccftpC0ZlR+0QU9cQAk1KtFUDsMI8bcPF6FXczi+brC223VTPh2+j1FMSjiovMpVDzO/GNyYKNDONwgakKJEWuo3BQG9Pfs6nSOC0oD8NgrqU8ymj3P+Gaqm1Ei8rQt3AO6TeReRgiOZpKpTugfad5kyLd44yOu2SGQ7s1i0ZbtcwVBuGz3efSyA==

# Requires Format PKCS#8   BEGIN PRIVATE KEY         
# If you have     PKCS#1   BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY  convert it by   openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -nocrypt -in sp.rsa_key -outform pem -out sp.pem
onelogin.saml2.sp.privatekey =

# Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
#

# Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
onelogin.saml2.idp.entityid = https://am.seat.vwgroup.com/ampki/sps/saml20idppki/saml20

# SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
# URL Target of the IdP where the SP will send the Authentication Request Message
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.url = https://am.seat.vwgroup.com/ampki/sps/saml20idppki/saml20/login
# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
# URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Request
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url = https://am.seat.vwgroup.com/ampki/sps/saml20idppki/saml20/slo

# Optional SLO Response endpoint info of the IdP.
# URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Response. If left blank, same URL as onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url will be used.
# Some IdPs use a separate URL for sending a logout request and response, use this property to set the separate response url
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.response.url =

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# Public x509 certificate of the IdP
onelogin.saml2.idp.x509cert = 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

# Instead of use the whole x509cert you can use a fingerprint
# (openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in "idp.crt" to generate it,
# or add for example the -sha256 , -sha384 or -sha512 parameter)
#
# If a fingerprint is provided, then the certFingerprintAlgorithm is required in order to
# let the toolkit know which Algorithm was used. Possible values: sha1, sha256, sha384 or sha512
# 'sha1' is the default value.
# onelogin.saml2.idp.certfingerprint = 
# onelogin.saml2.idp.certfingerprint_algorithm = sha1


# Security settings
#

# Indicates that the nameID of the <samlp:logoutRequest> sent by this SP
# will be encrypted.
onelogin.saml2.security.nameid_encrypted = false

# Indicates whether the <samlp:AuthnRequest> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.              [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
onelogin.saml2.security.authnrequest_signed = false

# Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutRequest> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.logoutrequest_signed = false

# Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutResponse> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.logoutresponse_signed = false

# Indicates a requirement for the <samlp:Response>, <samlp:LogoutRequest> and
# <samlp:LogoutResponse> elements received by this SP to be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.want_messages_signed = false

# Indicates a requirement for the <saml:Assertion> elements received by this SP to be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_signed = true

# Indicates a requirement for the Metadata of this SP to be signed.
# Right now supported null (in order to not sign) or true (sign using SP private key) 
onelogin.saml2.security.sign_metadata = true

# Indicates a requirement for the Assertions received by this SP to be encrypted
onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_encrypted = false

# Indicates a requirement for the NameID received by this SP to be encrypted
onelogin.saml2.security.want_nameid_encrypted = false

# Authentication context.
# Set Empty and no AuthContext will be sent in the AuthNRequest
# You can set multiple values (comma separated them)
onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontext = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password

# Allows the authn comparison parameter to be set, defaults to 'exact'
onelogin.saml2.security.onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontextcomparison = exact


# Indicates if the SP will validate all received xmls.
# (In order to validate the xml, 'strict' and 'wantXMLValidation' must be true).
onelogin.saml2.security.want_xml_validation = true

# Algorithm that the toolkit will use on signing process. Options:
#  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha384'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512'
onelogin.saml2.security.signature_algorithm = http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

# Organization
onelogin.saml2.organization.name = APP 
onelogin.saml2.organization.displayname = Seat APP
onelogin.saml2.organization.url = https://app.seat.vwg
onelogin.saml2.organization.lang = en-US

# Contacts
onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.given_name = Soporte
onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.email_address = soporte@domain.com
onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.given_name = Soporte 2
onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.email_address = soporte2@domain.com
```

When I try to run on server the sample webapp, I'm getting a FBTSML224E error from IBM Tivoli:
[image]

> Explanation
>   The required configuration for the partner provider cannot be found.
>   System action
>   The operation will be halted.
>   Administrator response
>   Ensure that the partner provider's metadata has been imported into this federation and that the configuration file is not corrupted.

I'm stuck at this point, could someone please help me?

Comment: If you already have a Spring-based web app, then you may look at Spring Security SAML extentions. You basically need to create your SP meta data and provide the IdP meta data.

Comment: Go through sample project, it's explaination : https://github.com/wasilzafar/identitytester

Comment: @WZee Thank you so much, I will check it out deeply. At least, the project works normally after I imported it into my workspace :)